# OpenGL: depth calculations are discontinuous

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm building a LIDAR simulator in OpenGL. This means that the fragment shader returns the length of the light vector (the distance) in place of one of the color channels, normalized by the distance to the far plane (so it'll be between 0 and 1). In other words, I use red to indicate light intensity and blue to indicate distance; and I set green to 0. Alpha is unused, but I keep it at 1.

Here's my test object, which happens to be a rock:

[image]

I then write the pixel data to a file and load it into a point cloud visualizer (one point per pixel) — basically the default. When I do that, it becomes clear that all of my points are in discrete planes each located at a different depth:

[image: Point cloud visualization]

I tried plotting the same data in R. It doesn't show up initially with the default histogram because the density of the planes is pretty high. But when I set the breaks to about 60, I get this:

[image: Density plot of distances (about 60 breaks)].

I've tried shrinking the distance between the near and far planes, in case it was a precision issue. First I was doing 1–1000, and now I'm at 1–500. It may have decreased the distance between planes, but I can't tell, because it means the camera has to be closer to the object.

Is there something I'm missing? Does this have to do with the fact that I disabled anti-aliasing? (Anti-aliasing was causing even worse periodic artifacts, but between the camera and the object instead. I disabled line smoothing, polygon smoothing, and multisampling, and that took care of that particular problem.)

### Edit

These are the two places the distance calculation is performed:

- The [vertex shader](https://github.com/mohawkjohn/lidargl/blob/008f45177f41a655fafa56735a935e48b785139f/lidarv.glsl) calculates `ec_pos`, the position of the vertex relative to the camera.
- The [fragment shader](https://github.com/mohawkjohn/lidargl/blob/008f45177f41a655fafa56735a935e48b785139f/lidarf.glsl) calculates `light_dir0` from `ec_pos` and the camera position and uses this to compute a distance.

Is it because I'm calculating `ec_pos` in the vertex shader? How can I calculate `ec_pos` in the fragment shader instead?

Comment: Have you tried using a floating-point depth buffer (default is fixed-point)? Usually there is not a lot of benefit to doing so save for a few special applications, but it looks like there may be in this case. Getting one could be a little difficult, they're easy to get using FBOs but using the default framebuffer you will have to look into your platform's window system API. I'm guessing it's either CGL or NSOpenGL in this case since this is running on OS X?

Comment: I also have to wonder how you are getting these distance values back? Is it actually the value stored in the depth buffer you are concerned about here, or is it one of the color components you computed? The color buffer is generally 8-bit fixed-point per-component as well. If you try to cram a depth value into there, it is going to exhibit weird things like this because you have given up *at least* 8-bits worth of precision (assuming a 16-bit depth buffer).

Comment: Changing depth clip planes does not correlate with camera position. Try setting planes to your objects `position` +/- `radius`

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman To be clear, I'm not using the depth buffer to calculate the distance for the purposes of the simulation. I tried that, and it actually produced some even stranger discontinuities. The distance is calculated manually, and I've included the links to the shaders now. I calculate a distance and store it in the blue channel.

Comment: @KromStern could you please clarify your comment? I'm not understanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: Do you account for Blue values being discrete in 0..255 range? I have trouble realizing your exact calculations formula, can you add it please?

Comment: It's just `vec3 light_dir0 = gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - ec_pos; float dist = length(light_dir0);` and the calculation of `ec_pos` in `lidarv.glsl`, @KromStern.

Comment: @mohawkjohn: Followed by `gl_FragColor.b = float_dist;` ?

Comment: Yeah. The code is linked directly above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible issues I can think of.

(1) Your depth precision.  The far plane has very little effect on resolution; the near plane is what's important.  See [Learning to Love your Z-Buffer](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html).

(2) The more probable explanation, based on what you've provided, is the conversion/saving of the pixel data.  The shader outputs floating point values, but these are stored in the framebuffer, which will typically have only 8bits per channel.  For color, what that means is that your floats will be mapped to the underlying 8-bit (fixed width, integer) representation, therefore only possessing 256 values.

If you want to output pixel data as the true floats they are, you should make a 32-bit floating point RGBA FBO (with e.g. `GL_RGBA32F` or something similar).  This will store actual floats.  Then, when your data from the GPU, it will return the original shader values.

I suppose you could alternately encode a single `float` in a `vec4` with some multiplication, if you don't have a FBO implementation handy.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about how to create such an FBO in GLSL 120? Or provide a link? =) Thanks.

Comment: A FBO (framebuffer object) is an _OpenGL_ feature, and is independent of GLSL.  If you're not familiar with FBOs, it's nontrivial OpenGL code--well out of the scope of a quick answer.  There are plenty of examples online.  At the risk of self-aggrandizement, various of my projects contain a FBO class (such as e.g. http://geometrian.com/programming/projects/index.php?project=Game%20of%20Life, written in Python, and which I think might support floating-point renderbuffers).

Comment: I'd really just like an example. There are a lot of FBO functions and I haven't been able to figure out if I need to generate and bind one every render cycle, or just during setup, or what.

Comment: That's the point; simple examples don't really exist.  You should Google around to figure out good usage.  My project linked above is one such example.